# Column values strip and grouping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

i have dataset of 10k+ rows and one of the column is Month/Year like-"APR-16".
and it is of datatype String.
it is a several year's of data so, i want to group the similar Year and i want to draw a time series plot here

Comment: You can start with the .str accessor and work form there. It is also good to state a concrete question/problem that you've tried to solve and failed, and give some information on what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is quite broad to give a valuable answer. As well you are suposed to search by yourself first then post your problem only. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> x="APR-16"
>>> x.split("-")
['APR', '16']
>>> x.split("-")[0]
'APR'
>>> x.split("-")[1]
'16'
```

(put reference to column in the dataframe instead of x)

Comment: You cannot apply String methods to a pandas.Series directly. You need to go through .str to use them.

Comment: I know, just the question was so ambiguous, that I gave very generic answer. If there would be some code provided - I would be more concrete.